# Using raspberry pico with pycharm - only main.py is working

Tags: pycharm, thonny, raspberry-pi-pico

I am using a Raspberry Pico and until now I have used Thonny for writing my code. Now I wanted to test PyCharm but I can't get a program that is not named main.py to run.
So when I click on "flash main.py" it works and the pico executes the code. But when I name the file anything else (e.g. like blink.py) and then flash it, it doesn't work. When I flash the same file using Thonny it works, so it can't be the code I guess.
Does anybody have any ideas what that could be? Or am I doing something wrong in PyCharm?

Thanks!

Comment: Where do you click on `flash main.py`?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related to your Pycharm configuration. By default Pycharm wants to write to the Pico (flash) using main.py. This configuration does not change if you switch between different files / tabs that you are viewing. You will have to change the configuration settings or create additional configurations.

This image shows the configuration settings:
[Pycharm editing configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4Udg.png)

Comment: For me didn't work neither separate configuration for file....only main.py working well